# Copying taxonomy term to custom field

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "listing", and a custom taxonomy called "listing_state".

I'm using formidable to create posts.   What I am trying to do is have two things happen when a user selects a state from the taxonomy drop down.

First, to set the taxonomy, which is what happens now.  But then at the same time, also have this selected state get copied to a custom field called "state".

The end result should be a listing that is classified by state, but that also holds that state name in a custom field as well.

Any ideas?   Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking into 'save_post' action:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'your_state_term_save' );

function your_state_term_save( $post_id ){

    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    //check if they selected your state term
    $state = isset($_POST['tax_input_field_name']) ? $_POST['tax_input_field_name'] : ''; //make sure of what the input name is here...

    //insert post meta
    update_post_meta($post_id,'state',$state);
}
```

This works by waiting till the post is saved and grabbing the taxonomy term right out of the `$_POST` vairable.

Comment: Hi  I tried but it doesn't work.  What do you mean by the field name?

My taxonomy is state and the fields it holds are ID, Name and Slug.

I would like to copy the name.

Thanks

Comment: Because you had some kind of custom dropdown box for selecting the state, I was not sure what the 'name' attribute of your select box was. (The 'name' attribute is the key that will be stored in the $_POST variable.  You need to look at the html and change out **tax_input_field_name** with the correct field name in your taxonomy meta box.

Comment: I was not able to get it to work.  But I did try my own solution and it's almost there.  Everything works except that the incorrect state is being inserted.  PS I'm doing the updates/saves through the WP Admin. Can you see what the issue is? Thanks

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_state' );
function add_state( $post_id ){
// Bail if we're doing an auto save
 if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
 //check if they selected your state term
$state = get_terms('state', 'name');
foreach ( $state as $state );
 //insert post meta
update_post_meta($post_id,'state',$state->name);
}